# What is logic explanation to how characters are drawn on the screen?

Tags: character-encoding, binary, boolean, logic, pixel

How the letters and numbers exist in the first place in the CPU. All u have is binary numbers that not even numbers it's more like 'on/off' of electric signal. I don't mean ASCII or converting binary to regular. 
My question is how the CPU knows that a character - number or letter drawn in specific way. Is there a code that tells to color some pixels by coordinates?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, of course.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_font

Comment: The question is both off-topic and too broad.

Answer (score 0):

The display is a matrix of pixels, each pixel can have a different color, colors are represented in binay on 32 bites, 64 bites etc,

There is software for setting a specific color for each pixel.
To answer to you question, the letters are draw by coloring pixels which is done by software so the CPU uses only 0 and 1